Appending a random number to an appended text input fields
Please note in input2 that the RanNum is entirely replacing the input value. I would like to append it. Where am I going wrong?
If the input1 is "hey hey", I want the output in the other 3 fields to be:
heyhey7@gmail.com (7 being a RanNum)
heyhey@gmail.com
heyhey@gmail.com



var min = 1;
var max = 9;
var RanNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
  
var input1 = document.getElementById('first_name');
var input2 = document.getElementById('email');
var input3 = document.getElementById('username');
var input4 = document.getElementById('location');

input1.addEventListener('change', function() {
  input2.value = input1.value.replace(/\s+/g,'').trim().value=RanNum + "@gmail.com";
  //input2.value = input1.value.replace(/\s+/g,'').trim() + .value=RanNum + "@gmail.com";
  input3.value = input1.value.replace(/\s+/g,'').trim() + "@gmail.com";
  input4.value = input1.value.replace(/\s+/g,'').trim() + "@gmail.com";
});
<input type="text" id="first_name" />
<input type="text" id="email" />
<input type="text" id="username" />
<input type="text" id="location" />




input1.value.replace(/\s+/g,'').trim().value=RanNum + "@gmail.com"; --> input1.value.replace(/\s+/g,'').trim() + RanNum + "@gmail.com";

@001 Such basics! Thank You so much. Please post as an answer.

You're doing some sort of weird double assignment where it's not needed. Drop the .value from what you have as you're already getting and manipulating it. Instead try:
input2.value = input1.value.replace(/\s+/g, '').trim() + RanNum + "@gmail.com";

or using a template literal:
input2.value = input1.value.replace(/\s+/g, '').trim() + `${RanNum}@gmail.com`;



var min = 1;
var max = 9;
var RanNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;

var input1 = document.getElementById('first_name');
var input2 = document.getElementById('email');
var input3 = document.getElementById('username');
var input4 = document.getElementById('location');

input1.addEventListener('change', function() {
  input2.value = input1.value.replace(/\s+/g, '').trim() + RanNum + "@gmail.com";
  input3.value = input1.value.replace(/\s+/g, '').trim() + "@gmail.com";
  input4.value = input1.value.replace(/\s+/g, '').trim() + "@gmail.com";
});
<input type="text" id="first_name" />
<input type="text" id="email" />
<input type="text" id="username" />
<input type="text" id="location" />



You could also tidy this up a bit with:


var min = 1;
var max = 9;
var RanNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;

var input1 = document.getElementById('first_name');
var input2 = document.getElementById('email');
var input3 = document.getElementById('username');
var input4 = document.getElementById('location');

input1.addEventListener('change', function() {
  input1val = input1.value.replace(/\s+/g, '').trim();
  input2.value = input1val + RanNum + "@gmail.com";
  input3.value = input1val + "@gmail.com";
  input4.value = input1val + "@gmail.com";
});
<input type="text" id="first_name" />
<input type="text" id="email" />
<input type="text" id="username" />
<input type="text" id="location" />



